# 'Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute'

Tags: c#

When I create a WPF project using VS2019 Community 16.9.4 I keep getting the `Could not load type System.Diagnostics` etc error message on Build while WPF projects I had previously created using earlier versions of VS don't give me this message.

I am at a loss to see what is causing this project to invoke this message. Does anyone have any ideas?

The full error message is:

> Unknown build error, 'Could not load type
> 'System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute' from
> assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I got to the bottom of this problem by process of elimination by comparing a project that works with one that doesn't and noticed that this issues was happening because a current day Telerik control was installed when I only have a license up to 2017. How that got translated into the above message is beyond me and completely threw me off the track.

I guess it's one to bare in mind where seemingly completely random things can happen.

Comment: I owe you a beer